# Select storyboard to launch on launchScreen completion

Tags: swift, xcode

After completion of launchScreeen(Splash) I want to be able to select which storyboard to launch. For example launch login.storyboard if user is not logged in or launch dashboard.storyboard if user is logged in. Currently Main.storyboard is launched after launchScreen. in appdelegate I have a code for checking the login status as follows:

---

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    var launchDashBoard = false
    let isUserLoggedIn = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: TAG_IS_USER_LOGGEDIN) as? Bool
    if isUserLoggedIn != nil {
        launchDashBoard = isUserLoggedIn!
    }
        if launchDashBoard {
            self.loadDashBoard()
        }else{
            self.loadIntro()
    }
    return true
}
    func loadHome(){
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let home = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dashboard") as! Dashboard
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: home)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
}
func loadLogin(_ viewController: UIViewController?){
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let home = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "signIn") as! SignInVC
    home.previousViewController = viewController
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: home)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController

}
```

---

If I run the app with this code it crashes with following log:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'
*** First throw call stack:
```

---

Is there a way to include a function that determines which storyboard to launch on launchScreen loading is finished or is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new Navigation.storyboard. That storyboard can have an initial view controller(Call it StartUpNavigationViewController), that will be opened when Launch screen has been shown.
In that StartUpNavigationViewController, check for the logic if the user is logged in or not, based on that you can navigate to login or dashboard storyboard.